# Select query where rows with same ID only return row with most recent date field

Tags: sql

I am having a little trouble figuring out how to do the below query. I want to return a row for every unique id in table 1 even if date is null but if there is multiple rows with the same ID I only want to return the id with the most recent date. Any help would be appreciated

```
Select  a.ID, a.[zip code], b.date
            from table1 a   

            left join table 2 b on a.ID = b.ID  
            Where a.[Zip Code] = '78701' 
Group by a.ID, a.[zip code], b.date
            Order by a.[zip code] asc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to select only the maximum date in `table2` for each ID:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.[zip code], b.date
FROM table1 a   
LEFT JOIN (SELECT ID, MAX(date) AS date
           FROM table2
           GROUP BY ID) b ON a.ID = b.ID  
WHERE a.[Zip Code] = '78701' 
ORDER BY a.[zip code] ASC
```

Comment: Thats great! Anyway to get that in a group by instead of a sub query?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. What are you hoping to group, exactly? (Showing sample input and desired output in the question can help clear this up.)

Comment: Just scratch that question ;) Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You could also have the same result by changing your query:

```
SELECT    a.ID, a.[zip code], MAX(b.date) AS [date]
FROM      table1 AS a    
              LEFT JOIN table2 AS b 
                  ON a.ID = b.ID  
WHERE     a.[Zip Code] = '78701' 
GROUP BY  a.ID, a.[zip code]
ORDER BY  a.[zip code] ASC ;
```